# C# Update the contents of a dataGridview when the XML its using as a source is modified?

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

The application I've been working on takes user input from a form, and builds nodes in an XML file from this user input. On the mainform, when the index of a combo box is changed, the contents of this xml file are parsed, looking for the inner text of of the nodes that match the selected index, then displays the results in a datagridview on the mainform.....

What I'd like to do if enable the datagridview to automatically update whenever a new node matching the selected index is created in the XML file. IE I add a new account to an account list....the datagridview updates, without having to click on the combobox again.

How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that there's anything built-in to do this. I think you'd need to use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to spot that the file had changed on disk, reparse the file, and rebind the DataGridView. It probably won't be hard to do, although you should remember that the FSW won't fire events on the UI thread by default. That's probably a *good* thing for you though - do all the parsing in a different thread, and only do the binding in the UI thread, to avoid the UI becoming sluggish.